# Subreports in crystal report duplicating and too much padding in the data rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a sub report in my crystal report and when i run it i notice the  report is duplicating according to the number of rows in the report and also has too much space in between the rows

Comment: where did you place the sub report on design?

Comment: in one of the details section i created

Comment: move it to the header section or for the footer section